# How can i pull a date's number from a scenario example and use it to move my date x day(s) in adv and then convert it to STRFTIME?

Tags: ruby, datetime, case, strftime

I am having problems understanding how to strip the number '2' from "2 days from now" and then use that to increment my date by two days. so something like date = (Date.today + 2).strftime('%a %-e') aka two days forward.

My 'puts' are just so i can see if the correct date is being outputted. In this situation i am having problems with the third case.

As you can see, I need, verbatim, the date to equal "Thur 26 Tasks"

```
And(/^I can see the correct task lists details for (.*)$/) do |date|

  sleep 1
  case
  when date == ("today")
    date = Date.today.strftime('%a %-e') + " Tasks"
    puts date
  when date == ("tomorrow")
    date = (Date.today + 1).strftime('%a %-e') + " Tasks"
    puts date
  when date.downcase.include?("days from now")
    date = ((Date.today + [/\d*/]) + " Tasks")
    puts date
  end
  TasksPage.todays_tasks_title.click unless exists {$driver.text(date)}
```

end

Comment: What is `And` ?

Comment: If you are confident that `date` begins with a digit, you could simply use `date.to_i` to get its integer value.

Comment: If you found either answer helpful please consider selecting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As idea for you

```rb
date = "3 days from now"

date = "#{(Date.today + date.match(/\A\d+(?!days from now\z)/)[0].to_i).strftime('%a %-e')} Tasks" if date.match?(/\A\d+ days from now\z/)
# => "Fri 29 Tasks"
```

`date.match?(/\A\d+ days from now\z/)` returns `true` or `false`

`date.match(/\A\d+(?!days from now\z)/)[0]` returns substring with days quantity (`"3"`).

Negative lookahead `(?!...)` used here.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'date'

def doit(str)
  n = case str
  when /\btoday\b/
    0
  when /\btomorrow\b/
    1
  when /\bdays from now\b/
    str[/\d+/].to_i
  else
    nil
  end
  n.nil? ? nil : (Date.today+n).strftime('%a %-e Tasks')
end

doit "today"                 #=> "Tue 26 Tasks" 
doit "No rain today?"        #=> "Tue 26 Tasks" 
doit "todayornottoday"       #=> nil 
doit "tomorrow"              #=> "Wed 27 Tasks" 
doit "2 days from now"       #=> "Thu 28 Tasks" 
doit "1 Monday from now"     #=> nil
```